# SSIS 2012 Development how to secure passwords

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012, ssdt-bi, ssis

In SSIS 2008 we used a configuration table in on a SQL Server to store all our passwords, then easily retrieved those with package configurations. This worked both in production and development when running the package from Visual Studio.

I'm trying to upgrade packages to 2012 project model and store them in the SSIS catalog to take advantage of the environment variables.

But when we are doing development in Visual Studio, we cannot retrieve those variables from the catalog. The only way I've found to maintain passwords in the package parameters is to manually type them in and save sensitive data using a password or user key. This seems like a big step backwards - I just recently managed to get rid of the last password in our packages - do I now have to start adding passwords again??

Am I missing something? How do people store their sensitive data during project development using Visual Studio in SSIS 2012?

Thanks,

Reinis

Answer (score 0):

In 2012, the default deployment mode is project deployment. One way is to turn it into package deployment. The other way is use parameter to pass the password and binding with the environment variable in SSMS.

Comment: As far as I could figure out, there's no way to bind an environment variable from the catalog to a project being run in Visual Studio - the only way to give VS the password is by hardcoding it in the parameter.